# SSRS Current Document Map Display

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has document map on two columns...

I am trying to display the currently selected data (CAF SA -> PP5566) on its own page (using page breaks between groups) with the report name and code above the table of data, an example show below with the arrows:

[image]

So if I click the next code it will change data accordingly:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, it looks like you have this already?

Comment: Apologies Alan, the string shown at arrows is a mock up of what i want, that is just an edit in paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would probably do it based on what I know.

The following example uses the Microsoft supplied Northwind sample database in case you want to reproduce this.

First I created a dataset pointing to the Northwind database using the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       r.RegionID, r.RegionDescription
       , t.TerritoryID, t.TerritoryDescription
       , e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName
       , c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName
    FROM Region r
       join Territories t on r.RegionID = t.RegionID
       join EmployeeTerritories et on t.TerritoryID = et.TerritoryID
       join Employees e on et.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
       join Orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
        join Customers c on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

This will give us Region (the top group level), Territory (second group level) and some employee names and customer names which we can use in the detail part.

Next, added a tablix (table) and  dragged the first name, last name & company name onto it. This will be the details row.
Next I right-clicked the details group in the row group panel and chose 'Add Group => Parent Group', set the group by to 'TerritoryDescription' and checked the 'Add group header' option before clicking OK.
Next I right clicked on the new TerritoryDescription group and repeated the above, this time using 'RegionDescription'

On territory row I added some static text into the 3rd column (under FirstName) and the territory description field as the expression for the 4th column (under last name). Now right-click on Territory static text you just added and choose "Insert Row => Inside group Above". Add static "Region" text and region field into column 3 and 4 respectively

I added a page header and footer just to it looks clearer when viewing on screen.

Next delete the first two columns as we no longer need these, select 'delete column only' if prompted.

Now double-click the `TerritoryDescrition` group in the row groups panel, click 'Advanced' and set the document map to 'TerritoryDescription'.
Repeat this for the RegionDescription row group selecting 'RegionDescription' this time for the document map.

The final design looked like this...

[image]

I set the report 'InteractiveSize' height to 15cm for clarity.

When the report is run I get this..

[image]

If I drill down to a differnt Region and Territory, I get this..

[image]

Comment: Spot on Alan, thank you for the very detailed example, helped me massively, cheers mate.